# Formatting value in directive angularjs

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am successfully able to call a directive whose data is received from an AJAX call using a factory. One of the values I receive is in Unix timestamp format and I need to convert it to human-readable format using something like,

```
new Date(date*1000);
```

What is the best way to format this value (info.dt) and place it back in the directive?

1. Do I need to use link in the directive?
2. Can I specify a filter?

Code details:

My directive,

```
mist.directive('weatherToday', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        templateUrl: "pages/tw.html",
        scope: {info: '='}
    };
});
```

tw.html, (I need to convert **info.dt** to human-readable date-time format.)

```
<div>

    <h1>{{info.dt}}</h1>
</div>
```

the directive is called like so,

```
<weather-today info="weather"></weather-today>
```

Factory details:

```
WeatherService.getTodaysData().then(
    function (data) {
        $scope.weather = data;
        }
);

mist.factory('WeatherService', function ($http) {
    return {
        getTodaysData: function () {
        return $http.get('http://example.com').then(function (result) {
        return result.data;
        });
    }
}});
```

Comment: Use the [date filter](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/date)

Comment: I tried using  {{info.dt| date:'short'}} but the value returned is different than when I call new Date(date*1000); which is why I want to know if we can call a function and pass this value and then return a different value.

Comment: and it works? I made a working [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/hmFwTHckN95DikDF5EP1?p=preview)

Comment: Thanks for that. Ok, you have dt: new Date(). but in my case, its like this dt: 1437714160. Since I get the value from a service/factory, I'm not sure how or where to format it.

Comment: Why `place it back in the directive?`. Just keep a valid `Date` format value on the directive. When displayed on the view, use `date.filter`. Format it when you get the number `dt: 1437714160`, i.e., in the factory, to a `Date` object.

Comment: Add do your post what `weather` is in your scope

Comment: Ok, Maybe I'll do that.  I was also thinking of creating a custom filter because I need to use it in another module that uses an array of date-time in a similar format. Is it possible to do this using, function link(scope, element, attrs) { ... }

Comment: So what you actually need is a service/factory/provider to format the Unix timestamp to a Date object. And then reuse this service/factory/provider to where needed.

Comment: `{{info.dt * 1000| date:'short'}}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `factory` is to provide the data and to be reused by other code. So, format the Unix timestamp to a `Date` object inside the factory. So that the users of this factory do not need to repeat the formatting.

```
mist.factory('WeatherService', function ($http) {
    // You may want to extract this function to an independent factory/service
    function formatUnixDate (timestamp) {
        // Return the formatted Date.
    }
    return {
        getTodaysData: function () {
        return $http.get('http://example.com').then(function (result) {
            // Suppose the `data` is an Array.
            result.data = result.data.map(function (item) {
                item.myDate = formatUnixDate(item.myDate);
                return item;
            });
            return result.data;
        });
    }
}});
```